# Schedule report with Privileged Identity Management

Tags: powerbi

We got a report in PowerBI that requires global admin rights and needs to be scheduled. We're using PIM, so nobody has permanent admin rights. So, to make the report work, I need to activate admin roles first, and than refresh the report.
Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score -1):

You can use scheduled activation in PIM where you can select a specific time when you would be activated automatically. You can then have a scheduled task which refreshes the report around the same time.

Comment: Can I schedule admin rights to be activated like every Monday morning with PIM?

Comment: Definitely. There is no recurrence yet but you can select multiple datetimes.